# Finding the Crossing number of $K_{4,4}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, np-complete

I am struggling to find the crossing number of the complete bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$. The best range I can get to is $\text{cr}(K_{4,4}) \leq 16$ (obtained by putting all vertices onto a regular octagon), which is still messy of course.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ok I got the crossing lessened to 4. Is 4 the smallest crossing?

Comment: $4$ is the [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_brick_factory_problem#Upper_bound) given by Zarankiewicz and Urbanik; the Zarankiewicz crossing number conjecture is that this bound is optimal. It stands to reason that someone would have noticed by now if $K_{4,4}$ afforded a counterexample to this conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

We see that $cr(K_{4,4})\leq4$ by placing the partite sets in a way that they are normal to each other.

Next, if the crossing number is less than 4, removing some 3 edges from $K_{4,4}$ would result in a planar graph. Now, by Euler's formula ($v-e+f=2$), we conclude that this new graph has $7$ faces. Since the original graph was bipartite, every face must be bounded by at least $4$ edges (bipartite graphs have only even cycles). Therefore, the sum of bound degree $\sigma \geq 28$. At the same time, $\sigma \leq 2\cdot 13=26$, a contradiction. Thus, $cr(K_{4,4}) = 4$.

Comment: I'm sure "placing the partite sets in a way that they are normal to each other" makes sense in your head, but if I didn't already know what the construction looked like, this would not help me. At the very least, we can give coordinates: "Place the vertices on one side of the bipartition at $(-2,0), (-1,0), (1,0), (2,0)$ and the vertices on the other side at $(0,-2), (0,-1), (0,1), (0,2)$; draw the edges as straight line segments." A picture is better.

Comment: I suppose since you are self-answering, you have less motivation to write a detailed description...